# HTAccess Protecting Files

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, subdirectory

I want to have an htaccess that protects files from being directly accessed. So here's my file structure:
[image: Files and Folders]

I already protected my folders with:

```
Options -Indexes
```

But someone can still type

```
www.domain.com/Folder/CSS/Styles.css
```

or

```
www.domain.com/Folder/Insert.php
```

And it would show them everything. How exactly do I protect these files with htaccess? I don't want anyone to be able to view them but I want the site to run correctly. Last time i tried

```
deny from all
```

And the entire website failed to load because all the files/folders were *completely* locked, not even the own website could access its things. I just don't want people typing in the file path into the url and view them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is not possible, as a web browser will need to be able to get the files.  You can try something like the following, within the protected directories.  Just know that it does not take a genius to use Firebug, or any other development tool, to easily view the output of those requests - spoofing headers is also very easy to do...

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "www.example.com" mysite

<Limit GET POST HEAD>
 Order Deny,Allow
 Deny from all
 Allow from env=mysite
</Limit>
```

In the case that you are not familiar with the syntax, one can also use mod_rewrite for the same purpose with a `[F]` to forbid.  (written for readability)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/Folder/?(.*)$ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www\.example\.com/ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://www\.example\.com/ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F]
</IfModule>
```

Please know that if you have a flash/silverlight/java application then you will need to ensure that it passes the proper referrer request header before applying a solution like this.

Comment: Oh right I understand that you can basically steal everything using firebug/inspector/etc. But what I really getting at is protecting sensitive php files and documents that contain important information, i don't want anyone that knows the filename to be able to navigate to it and view it. I think your solution will help fix that issue, right?

Comment: If it contains sensitive information then protect it:  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/auth.html

Comment: If I make a folder require authentication then does that follow through to the files? I can require auth for `www.domain.com/Folder` but I also need `www.domain.com/Folder/file.txt` to require auth

Comment: An .htaccess applies to the current and any child directories, unless explicitly overwritten in a child .htaccess.   This action covers all files within the directory structure.